# Crater-like features on thick leads soldering - is this a soldering defect and should I be worried?

Tags: soldering

I have bought a new motherboard and upon closer inspection of VRM chokes I found many of them have these crater-like features (defect?) on their on their leads. Is this some kind of a defect, should I be worried and how (if ever) should it be fixed?

I haven't turned the motherboard on.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you think it is a defect?

Comment: @Justme In my practice, I got used to such leads being uniformly covered in solder. If it is not a defect - I'll be happy to continue with the PC build :-)

Comment: I have reworded the question accordingly.

Comment: The second from the right in the top photo doesn’t look good, but it may be soldered well within the through-hole plating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If these are *inductors*, then those fat wire ends are quite likely the copper wire itself: not posts to which the coil wire has been internally attached.

A possible construction winds the coil, encase, seal, or pot it with two long wire ends protruding. Insulating enamel near the wire-end is stripped away. These wire ends might be then solder-plated to prevent the copper from oxidizing. For coils intended to be used on printed circuit boards, the wires would be cut-to-length.
A shear cut may be accurate enough, or a final abrading might get wire height within spec. The wire-ends in OP's photo show that wire-ends have been carefully dressed-to-length. In either end-treatment case, the copper wire end is exposed, with no solder-plate - this will oxidize while on the shelf, or during shipping. The plated wire should not suffer the same problem - if it did, it would be considered a **serious fault**.

Why not solder-plate the wires *after* trimming-to-length? The solder-plating may leave a nub of solder off the end, violating the lead-length spec.

---

When you judge the quality of solder connection to the PCB motherboard, put far more emphasis on the quality of the solder fillet between the protruding wire, and the surrounding PCB pad. The fillet should be smooth. You can only hope that solder has adhered to the wire plating within the PCB plated-through hole:
[image: wire-to-pad PCB fillet]

 Any solder on the wire-end contributes little to current flow, and is less important than the fillet. However, the fact that the wire-end has oxidized, preventing flux from doing its job is not an encouraging sign.

Comment: Is the answer to the question "No" ? It is not an assembly defect (in Class 2 anyway), and would in my view not have any functional impact on the product that an end user could detect.

Answer (score 10):

The leads are not fully covered by solder and it looks like (but difficult to tell from this picture) that the copper is exposed.

Usually, leads are plated with either gold or tin (or some other metals) to prevent oxidation and allow a better wetting while soldering, but when cut, copper can be exposed, which will oxidize, this is why cut leads should be fully covered by solder.

From the picture, it is difficult to tell whether copper is exposed, however, if it happens to be the case, while technically a defect, it most likely won't be a problem for the lifespan and operating condition of a computer motherboard.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the circles those are vias, they are copper plated holes that allow electricity to go between layers in the PCB.

If you're talking about the triangles that are attached to each through hole solder point, those are most likely thermal relief pads connected to the through-hole points so that when soldering occurs during manufacturing, it doesn't break the traces.

If you're talking about the little indentations in the solder it's probably just an artifact from wave soldering and will have no effect on the conductivity of the board to the through hole parts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was talking about the "craters" on the lead ends. From what I can tell, vias and triangles look good. It is those craters I haven't seen before and they got me worried.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers tell enough about the soldering itself, but I'll try to tell more about the function. This is one of those situations where in a perfect world you'd want to avoid the craters, but in an imperfect world it's so far down the list of things that might break your build that you shouldn't worry about it. **It's part of the production process and part of the specified parameters.**

It's VRM, low-voltage DC. Yes, it's switched, but it's not as sensitive as HF electronics. It doesn't even do the full power-supply, it's part of a stabilizer circuit. If this is part of a multi-phase VRM system, the system is so far redundant that one or two bad connections going bad won't kill performance. Only if you blow out one or more phases entirely (for example, burn out a couple of FETs) should performance reduction be measurable.

Worst-case the components behind it will work for a (slightly) shorter period of time and even then you'll only run into that during severe overclocking. There's a much higher risk of one of your components being bad (inductor having a lower-than-specified saturation current, insufficient heat dissipation, stability, etc.) than this soldering turning into any problems.

As for how it should be 'fixed', please don't. VRM choke leads are thick and connected to serious power planes (thus heat dissipation) that make soldering any parts on them incredibly frustrating. Doing that by hand is possible, but you'll likely damage the board more than you're fixing.